Oracle - Mysterious Case statement
I've been experiencing something I haven't been able to figure out.
I have a simple case statement that is structured as follows:
Case when A in ('Status1', 'Status2', 'Status3') then 0 else 1 end derived_flag

I'm getting random results where the derived_flag is returning a NULL value and it's always just one record. What makes things more interesting is that it's not always the same record.
I'm obviously missing something but I don't see how a null value is possible given the else clause.
Any thoughts?
I'm not sure where to begin to be honest. This seems very straight forward to me regarding the expected results. I don't see how NULL could be an option with the else clause present.
Many Thanks

Please edit your question to show the whole query, or a minimal version shat shows the behaviour. I'd guess you are evaluating this in a subquery you outer join to, but who knows.

Not reall possible. See example. The issue must be somewhere else.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
